# Windows phone - You have installed the maximum number of development app

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows

I have a windows app that's running for a while and recently when I'm trying to deploy the application on windows phone running windows 8.1 OS(using visual studio 2013 and windows phone application deployment) I'm getting the following error:

```
"You have installed the maximum number of development apps. These apps are installed to your device when you start them in Visual Studio or when you use the App Deployment Tool. Please uninstall one of them and then try again."
```

I've tried to reset the phone, renaming the app and the phone on windows explorer, unregister & register the phone and also uninstalling all the other applications on it.

The problem is happening on two different devices Nokia Lumia 630 & Nokia Lumia  920.

Is there another way to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The same problem appeared for me today. I wonder if it's connected to the date (November 1st). I haven't found a way to fix it either

Comment: I started experiencing this several days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fix now and we can register our Windows Phone 8.1 for developing:
[image]
Could you please try to unregister the Phone from the Dev Center and register Phone again to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the problem is fixed. At least it works for me again. Thank you

Comment: The problem was fixed.